# Does the natural (asymptotic) density of a set A change if a subset of A with natural density zero is subtracted from A?

Tags: number-theory, limits, probability-theory, asymptotics

I know that given two subsets of the Naturals *A* and *B*, if the natural density of *A* equals some non-zero real number *a*, and the natural density of *B* is zero, then the natural density of the *symmetric difference* of *A* and *B* is still *a*. But what are the properties of just *set difference* with respect to natural density? That is, suppose we have the sets *A* and *B*, with respective natural densities as above. Would the natural density of the set difference *A-B* still be *a*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A\setminus B=A\Delta (B\cap A)$, and $B\cap A$ still has density zero since $B$ does and $B\cap A\subseteq B$.

Comment: Of course. Thanks!